# How would I debug CKAN using a breakpoint based debugger in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: python, django, debugging, visual-studio-code, ckan

I'm a fairly experienced developer just recently diving into the world of Python development via CKAN as an entrypoint.

So far, I understand very simple configurations, like running a single python file, setting a breakpoint, and waiting for it to be hit. That much I can follow because it's obvious to me where the application starts up. With CKAN, I'm not quite sure where I'd even run the debugger from.

However, when it comes to a more extensive system like CKAN (or perhaps others like Django), I haven't been able to quite figure out how all the pieces come together. Typically I'll start up a dev server using `paster serve` and it will run a webserver on port 5000. Using this knowledge as a baseline, what steps might I take to get to the point where I can place a breakpoint in an extension, start up CKAN, wait for the breakpoint to be hit, and then inspect the current values of variables and so on?

FWIW, I'm running CKAN in production on Ubuntu 14.04 and in development on macOS 10.11 in a virtualenv.

I feel like the problems I'm facing might be because the various components of CKAN, and python as a whole, seem rather abstract to me and understanding them at a deeper level might help me reason about the stack a little better.

Answer (score 1):

After some searching I discovered that CKAN is using [Pylons](https://pylonsproject.org/) and [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) under the covers. This allowed me to search for other debugging configurations based on these frameworks.

The configuration I ended up using was this:

```html
"configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "stopOnEntry": false,
            "pythonPath": "${config:python.pythonPath}",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/bin/paster",
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}/src",
            "env": {},
            "envFile": "${workspaceRoot}/.env",
            "args": [
                "serve",
                "/etc/ckan/default/development.ini"
            ],
            "exceptionHandling": {
                "ignore": ["ImportError"]
            }
        }]}
```

pythonPath: points to the python binary local to the virtualenv

program: points to the paster script which is pylons' cli and the program used to typically initiate a development server for CKAN

args: each item can be thought of as a component of a concatenated string that is then passed as command to the "program". "serve" is the paster command typically used to start a ckan dev server and the second argument is the CKAN config file it requires as an arg.

Nothing complicated going on here.

Thanks to Sean from byatool.com for [this article](http://byatool.com/uncategorized/how-to-debug-pylons-with-pycharm/) which helped immensely.